# Solenoid force output and stroke distance

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid

I have a question about the forces a given solenoid can really output. While I can find literature about the forces that are being exerted in a given point in space by the plunger I'm questioning if the distance the plunger traveled matters. To better illustrate my idea, comparing two cases, one which I activate the solenoid very close to the end of the course, where the electromagnetic forces are higher will have a different force output of activating it at the very beginning of the course, where the forces are lower, make the full movement, and when it is closer to the end, it already has an acceleration > 0, and then hit or actuate something. In my mind, the forces should be different, one case, at least, should have more energy than the other, or am I wrong? And how would I calculate this force?

Comment: Yes the distance matters; the reluctance of the air gap is inversely proportional to its length.

Comment: thanks. Yes, the distance matters for the absolute force it will output on that point. But my question is also about the motion. Put simply: the core having an acceleration > 0 / velocity > 0 will have a higher force output at that given position when compared to having acceleration = 0 and velocity = 0.

Comment: Just calculate the final momentum for both cases.